# Swift - TableView background image: how to center the image

Tags: swift, image, tableview

I want to add a logo as a background image to my `tableView`. Image size is 50px, 50px.

I tried the code below, but this puts the image lower right corner.

```
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "logo"))
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.layer.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.midX, y: self.view.frame.midY, width: 50, height: 50)
    let tableViewBackgroundView = UIView()
    tableViewBackgroundView.addSubview(imageView)
    self.tableView.backgroundView = tableViewBackgroundView
```

Comment: The `x` and `y` values in the `CGRect` initializer are for the top left corner.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few points about swift that are pretty key:

1) The x and y parameters in CGRect.init(x:y:width:height:) don't refer to the center of the imageView. Instead, they are points in a coordinate system where (0, 0) is the *Upper Left Corner* of the view that the CGRect is being presented over, and

2) UIImageView actually inherits from UIView, so because of this you can just say

```
    tableView.backgroundView = imageView
```

You shouldn't have to fiddle around with any CGRects, I believe this code should work just fine, although you may have to fiddle with different contentMode properties to get it to display how you like.

```
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "logo"))
    imageView.layer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
    imageView.layer.frame.midX = tableView.layer.frame.midX 
    imageView.layer.frame.midY = tableView.layer.frame.midY
    tableView.backgroundView = imageView
```

Comment: If the code above doesn't work, try                                                                                              `imageView.bounds = rightTableView.layer.bounds`                                                        before you set the imageView as the backgroundView

Comment: I removed CGRect, imageView covers the whole tableView. I want a small logo at the center of the tableView.

Comment: In that case, it might be easier to do this using storyboards so you can constrain it using autolayout, but you could still do it by using your original CGRect init but adding

`imageView.layer.frame.midX = tableView.layer.frame.midX`
`imageView.layer.frame.midY = tableView.layer.frame.midY`

I've updated my answer to include this